# Javascript: Writing HTML dynamically via innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Im not sure why I cannot dynamically write to the paragraph element.  I've even tried with just a string  to no avail.  What am I doing wrong here?  Im guessing the default behavior is to POST because that's all that happens, even though I'm not telling it to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function submit() { 

    var fName = "";
    var lName = ""; 
    var eLevel = "";

    fName = document.person.elements["fName"].value; 
    lName = document.person.elements["lName"].value; 
    eLevel = document.person.elements["eLevel"].value; 

    var result = fName + " " + lName + "<br>" + eLevel;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result; 
};
//-->
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form action="" id="person">
        Please fill in all fields.<br /><br />

        <fieldset><legend>Name:</legend>
        First:  &nbsp;<input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" /><br /><br          />
        Last:&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" /> 
       </fieldset>
        <br />

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Education:</legend>
        Highest Level:&nbsp;
        <input list="eLevels" name="eLevel" />
        <datalist id="eLevels">
            <option value="High School">
            <option value="Associate Degree">
            <option value="Bachelors Degree">
            <option value="Graduate Degree">
        </datalist> 
     </fieldset>
        <br /><button value="click" onclick="submit()">click</button>

     </form>
     <p id="result"></p>
     </body>

</html>
```

Comment: innerHTML should hold valid html code. The value you are assigning to result is not proper html. Try enclosing it between <div> </div> tags and make sure it is valid html.

Comment: im sending a string to go between <p id="result">(innerHTML)</p>

Comment: Your sample code doesnot reflect that. If you are doing that by input consider it might be getting escaped, so would be without actual effect.

Comment: here it is condensed for you:

Comment: var result = fName + " " + lName + "<br>" + eLevel;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;

Comment: I created a string out of variables im pulling from the form and assigned them to a 'result' variable and passing that to innerHTML.  i even omitted this line and just did this:  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "TEST";  and it still doesn't work.  Im not sure why not...

Comment: Have you tried to inspect google chrome console to see any raising js exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `preventDefault` on the form submit, this way your code can execute.

```
function submit(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();

    var fName = "";
    var lName = ""; 
    var eLevel = "";

    fName = document.person.elements["fName"].value; 
    lName = document.person.elements["lName"].value; 
    eLevel = document.person.elements["eLevel"].value; 

    var result = fName + " " + lName + "<br>" + eLevel;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result; 
};
```

For the `event` parameter you will need to pass it in the `onClick()` event

```
<button value="click" onclick="submit(event)">click</button>
```

Comment: This answser is actually right, simply use e.preventDefault. jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/cd3vumrb/
Never the less, your code will be executed anyway, but the request makes the page to reload again if you dont prevent its default event behaviour on submit.

Comment: Sweet! that's it.  I just don't know what i was doing wrong.  I see you changed the datalist, thanks much.  I don't know how something so simple turned into something so complicated, lol..